# c++ STL sort with extra parameter 'invalid operator <'

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am trying to sort a not so small vector of strings with self-defined comparing rule which is here:

```
  bool lexGraph(string const &str1, string const &str2)
{
    string::const_iterator i1 = str1.begin(), i2 = str2.begin();

    while((i1 < str1.end()) && (i2 < str2.end()))
    {
        if(*i1 == ' ')
        {
            i1++;
            continue;
        }
        if(*i2 == ' ')
        {
            i2++;
            continue;
        }
        if(toupper(*i1) < toupper(*i2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(toupper(*i1) > toupper(*i2))
        {
            return false;
        }
        i1++, i2++;
    }
    return (str1.length() <= str2.length());
}
```

I use it in this loop:

```
vector<string> subset;
    ifstream fin(input);
    ofstream fout(output);
    string buff;
    for(long i = 0; i < 241; i++) 
    {
        getline(fin,buff);
        buff += '\n';
        subset.push_back(buff);

    }
sort(subset.begin(), subset.end(),lexGraph);
```

I found out that the overflow error occurs with vectors larger than 240. I found that this number can even become smaller if I use a smaller file. Also, strings are never really big. If I cut my function down to

```
bool lexGraph(string const &str1, string const &str2)
{
    return (str1.length() <= str2.length());
}
```

the error still occurs. But it doesnt when I use STL sort without an extra parameter.

So, I cant figure where the leak is and I hope for some hint here.

Comment: What do you mean by *overflow errors*? Also, what is `subset`?

Comment: a vector of strings. I added its declaration.

Comment: and *overflow errors*? what exactly does it mean here?

Comment: Does that comparator abide by the ordering rules? _Are you sure?_

Comment: I tried reproducing it with your cut down version, and I get a SIGSEGV when vector size is > 16.

Comment: Well, it isnt exactly an overflow. Earlier I ran the program with notepad and console and all I had was an appcrash. But MVS 2010 says: Line: 3665 Expression: invalid operator <. I am not very expereinced, what could this mean?

Comment: @JackSmith: If it's not an overflow, you would make things a lot easier for everyone by not *calling* it an overflow. IF you instead describe the actual error you're getting, people might be able to figure out what it means. If you just pick an arbitrary word at random and say that is your problem, it's kind of hard to diagnose.

Comment: Please read http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html then test your `lexGraph` maintains the invariants shown there

Comment: Note: You may want to change: `if(*i1 == ' ')` into `while((*i1 == ' ')&&(i1 != str1.end()))`

Comment: Note: This is unusual for iterators: `(i1 < str1.end())` it is more usual to see `(i1 != str1.end())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a strict-weak ordering. Your function for ordering must return false when called with equal strings. If you compare with `<=`, it doesn't work. BTW: I believe that some standard library implementations have a diagnostic mode that could have caught this error for you. Use this, as there are enough ropes in C++ that you can shoot yourself in the foot with.

Comment: I did not know you could shoot yourself with a rope.